# Remove escaped text from JSOUP parsed HTML

Tags: java, html, escaping, jsoup

I am parsing an HTML using JSOUP which contains some  elements as well.
However, when I print the resulting doc.html(), instead of  :

```
<script language="JavaScript"> <a href="http://www.company.com/index.htm" </a> </script>
```

I am getting :

```
<script language="JavaScript"> &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.company.com/index.htm&quot; &lt;/a&gt; </script>
```

In the code, I do a manipulation like the following :

```
for (final Element src : doc.select("script")) { 
data = data.replace(someText,newText);
src.text(data); <==== I could find this method escapes the text }
```

I am using UTF-8 char set.

How can I get the unescaped text directly ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have control of the HTML source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey thanks for all your help...
we solved the problem using :

```
src.childNode(0).attr("data", data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. The [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from Apache Commons seem to do the trick.

```
String html = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(document.html());
```

IMO it's not the best solution to this problem, but it works for me.

Comment: 10 years later, it's in the `commons-text` package.

Answer (score 0):

use the [`.html()`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html) method instead

```
src.html(data)
```